# How to fix node parent_id?

Tags: javascript

I’m setting up a data structure,and I want to fix node.

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  parent_id: 321
}, {
  id: 2,
  parent_id: 1
}, {
  id: 3,
  parent_id: 1
}, {
  id: 4,
  parent_id: 5
}, {
  id: 5,
  parent_id: 4
}];
const makeTree = (items, id, link = 'parent_id') => items.filter(item => item[link] == id).map(item => ({
  ...item,
  children: makeTree(items, item.id)
}));
console.log(makeTree(data));
```

If the node has a reference at `parent_id` that is not present in the collection, my code will not return anything. And it is necessary to return that node (no matter what his parent is not there). Wanted result is when my `{id: 1, parent_id: 321}` has two children `{id: 2, parent_id: 1}`, `{id: 3, parent_id: 1}`.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Wanted result is when my {id: 1, parent_id: 321} has two children {id: 2, parent_id: 1}, {id: 3, parent_id: 1}.

Comment: 0: {id: 1, parent_id: 321, children: Array(2)}
children: Array(2)
0: {id: 2, parent_id: 1}
1: {id: 3, parent_id: 1}
length: 2

Comment: please add the wanted result in literal notation to the question.

Comment: please explain the part with *"last node"* a bit more in detail.

Comment: why not `id: 5` and `id:4`? they have a circular reference.

Comment: Highest parent is id :1,because parent_id of id :2 is id:1.Same is for id:3.

Comment: If i put  id: 1, parent_id: null or 1 to 5,code will be ok and work.But if i put  parent_id: 6  or 361 or 2015,code will not return anything. I need to fix this.

Comment: please define "*highest*". is it the first one in the array? i have still problems to get what you mean with "**when**" something, then ... but in your question you do not have any identifier to hand over for the condition.

Comment: The highest parent is the one whose id is associated with parent_id other ids. In our case, this is id: 1. He has the most links. This is a tree data structure. My problem is that when we higest id or id: 1 in our case, it indicates a number that is not the number of id of the other objects in the array, for example, parent_id = 321, my code will not return anything, and I want that even if the highest parent shows a number of 321 or 888 or 6, it will still throw me out that he is the biggest parent, and not that he throws out anything, as in our case.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a staged approach by creating first the relation of all nodes, then get the depth of each node and filter by depth to get the largest. At the end, you get a part tree of the largest nodes.

```js
function getDepth({ id, children }, seen = new Set) {
    if (seen.has(id)) return 0; // prevent circular references
    if (!children) return 1;
    seen.add(id);
    return children.reduce((c, o) => c + getDepth(o, seen), 1);
}

function getRelations(data) {
    var t = {};
    data.forEach((o) => {
        Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
        t[o.parent_id] = t[o.parent_id] || {};
        t[o.parent_id].children = t[o.parent_id].children || [];
        t[o.parent_id].children.push(t[o.id]);
    });
    return t;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, parent_id: 321 }, { id: 2, parent_id: 1 }, { id: 3, parent_id: 1 }, { id: 4, parent_id: 5 }, { id: 5, parent_id: 4 }],
    relations = getRelations(data),
    longest = data
        .map(({ id }) => [id, getDepth(relations[id])])
        .reduce((r, a, i) => {
            if (!i || r[0][1] < a[1]) return [a];
            if (r[0][1] === a[1]) return r.push(a);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(([id]) => relations[id]);

console.log(longest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```